# Transferring data from nodeJS server to nodeJS server with completion event

Tags: node.js, events, file-transfer

I would like to bihourly send data from a calculation server to my hosting server. Once send the hosting server will load it in its memory and can then remove the old data from its memory to present the new data. For this I will need a download completion event. What would be the best approach for something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Does your servers located on the same machine ? If so you can use pipes.You can for example see [reference](http://www.sitepoint.com/basics-node-js-streams/)

Comment: Not really sure. They are both VPS at the same location (so different IP's). Would that work then?